# Rails: making an email pop-up box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail

I need the functionality to allow a user to send an email to another user. It would be ideal if they get a gmail pop-up with the user's email pre-filled. However, I'm unsure how I to approach this feature.

1) Is this possible?

2) If it is. How would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, assuming they have (and are signed into) Gmail, and have setup their machine to open mailto links with Gmail, just a `mailto:some.guy@gmail.com` link would do. You could also specify a subject by appending `?subject=This+is+a+test` to the end of the mailto link.

```
<a href='mailto:some.guy@gmail.com?subject=This+is+a+test'>Email Some Guy</a>
```